# Interpretation K-Means clustering with PCA

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, pca

I have implemented a K-Means clustering on a dataset in which I have reduced the dimensionality to 2 features with PCA.

[image: Clustering analysis plot here]

Now I am wondering how to interprete this analysis since there is any reference on which are the variables on the axis. Given that doubt, I am also wondering if it is a good practice implementg a K-Means on a resized dataset with PCA.

How can I interprete this kind of clustering?

Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? You could equally say "I've put things in 3 bins. Now what?"

Comment: My question was if there was any tool that I can use to help me interpret the data because i can't seem to find anything related to kmeans clustering +PCA

Comment: Interpret _how_? You presumably had some criteria you want to solve for

Comment: for exemple which columns vary the most in each cluster etc..

Comment: hum okay I'll adjust my question sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give an answer addressing your question since it is not specific enough and I have no idea about the data and the objective question of your research. So, let me answer your question in general perspective if it helps.

First of all, PCA strictly decreases interpretability of the analysis beacuse it reduces the dimensions depending on linear relations of variables and you can not name reduced components anymore. In addition, check the correlation scores among the variables before PCA to get intiution how much PCA will be successful and check variance explained by PCA. The lower explained variance ratio, the greater the information loss. So it may mislead your intreptations.

If your objective is to analyse data and make inferences, I would suggest you not to reduce dimension. You have 3 dimensions only. You can apply K-Means without PCA and plot them in 3D. Matplotlib and plotly provide interactive feature for this.

However, If your objective is to build a macine learning model, then you should reduce the dimension if they are highly correlated. This would be a big favor for your model.

Finally, applying K-Means after PCA is not something not to do but creates difficulty for interpretations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice ! I really do appreciate it :D made my night thx sir !